# How to get accuracy completion days count from input date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

How to get accuracy completion days count from given input date

```
  func floatDifferenceDays() -> Double {
    let current = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let   inputDate : String = "2018-07-15 05:46:12"
    let input = dateFormatter.date(from: inputDate)
    var result = current.timeIntervalSince(input!)
    result = result / 86400
    return result
}
```

Its zero. since the cycle of days datecomonents.day till 31 and increments to Month followed by year.

How can get the days that cycle have taken place which not include year,months.

if given inputdate 12 hours back from current date its should return 0.5 days completed

Comment: `DateComponents` won't deliver a fractional day - You would need to retrieve, say, hours and then divide by 24.

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated My question with an solution! its full needs but need to know is that valid approch

Comment: It isn't a good idea to divide by 86400 - It doesn't account for daylight savings time changes.  Better to retrieve the hours from date components.

Comment: @Paulw11 In my case daylight saving is an exceptional!  but future reference associated with daylight then your point is absolutely correct.

Comment: Why do you want to divide the number of seconds by 86400?  It doesn't make sense unless you want to know the number of days since January 1st, 1970.

Comment: 86400 is the number of seconds in a (normal) day, so dividing gives a value in fractional days.

Comment: @Paulw11 one layman question there thus system time for daylight saving automatically adjusted?  since we need not worried about daylight saving (tropical region)

Comment: `Calendar` takes all of that into account.  Even if you don't have DST, you do have leap years - For example Between Feb 26 and March 1 is 3 days in a normal year and 4 days in a leap year.  Calendar even accounts for leap seconds.   Even if you don't need this accuracy it is better to do it "right" and have code that works in every time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `Calendar` and `DateComponents` to get the correct elapsed time between two dates.  This will cater for leap years and daylight savings time changes.

E.g.

```
let current = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
let timezone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let inputDate = "2018-07-15 05:46:12"
if let input = dateFormatter.date(from: inputDate) {
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.hour], from: input, to: current)
    let days = Float(components.day ?? 0)
    let hours = Float(components.hour ?? 0)
    let elapsed = days + hours/24.0
    print("elapsed time is \(elapsed) days")
}
```

> elapsed time is 366.25 days

Note that this code assumes that the input string is in the "local" timezone; If it isn't you would need to make appropriate changes.

Comment: Yes the input string is local time Zone, I added below for even checking difference change for minuets and seconds difference elapsed value will assign to my progressView                                                                                                            let minutes = Float(components.minute ?? 0)
            let seconds = Float(components.second ?? 0)
             elapsed = days + hours/24.0  + minutes/(24 * 60.0) + seconds/(24 * 60.0 * 60.0)